# Multiple HTML5 Websockets - when one connection fails all remaining websocket connections are delayed

Tags: html, websocket

I have a project that uses multiple HTML5 websocket connections on the same page.  When all connections are available, the page functions as expected.  However, when one or more of the websocket connections are down, all remaining connections are blocked until the bad connection times out.  After timeout, the remaining websockets connect as expected.

Note the `uris` array below.  I have purposely added a bad websocket address to re-create this issue.  When the `each` loop fires, the first uri connects immediately and updates a `li` tag in the html.  The browser then hangs on the second (bad) uri for as long as 60 seconds before finally moving to the third uri which also connects immediately.

I was able to re-create this issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/eXZA6/2/

Javascript

```
var uris = {
    '1': 'ws://echo.websocket.org/', 
    '2': 'ws://echo.websocket.org:1234/', //Bad websocket address
    '3': 'ws://echo.websocket.org/'
};

var sockets = {};

$.each(uris, function(index, uri) {
    sockets[index] = connect(index, uri);
});

function connect(index, uri) {
    var websocket = new WebSocket(uri);

    websocket.onopen = function (evt) {
        $('li#' + index).text('Connected');
    };

    websocket.onclose = function (evt) {
        $('li#' + index).text('Closed');
    };

    websocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
    $('li#' + index).text('Received: ' + evt.data)
    };

    websocket.onerror = function (evt) {
        $('li#' + index).text('Error');
    };

    return websocket;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="connection">
    <li id="1" />
    <li id="2" />
    <li id="3" />
</ul>
```

- I tried using setTimeout and other hacky multi-thread tricks with no luck.
- Oddly enough, the functionality I expected appears to work in IE10, but not Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Firefox and Chrome are following the rules outlined in the WebSocket Spec [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), and IE10 isn't.

[Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.1): Client Requirements:

```
   2.  If the client already has a WebSocket connection to the remote
       host (IP address) identified by /host/ and port /port/ pair, even
       if the remote host is known by another name, the client MUST wait
       until that connection has been established or for that connection
       to have failed.  There MUST be no more than one connection in a
       CONNECTING state.  If multiple connections to the same IP address
       are attempted simultaneously, the client MUST serialize them so
       that there is no more than one connection at a time running
       through the following steps.
```

That essentially says that the behavior you are experiencing is the required behavior of a websocket client in order to be compliant with the spec.

Note the use of the word "MUST", an important and well defined key word in spec documents.  This key word, along with others, are specifically called out in [Section 2: Conformance Requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-2).

Comment: Interesting - I was unaware that the spec specifically prevented this behavior.  Do you know if there is a better approach to what I'm trying to do?  Is there a way to adjust the timeout before WebSocket moves on to the next connection?